# How to change certain characters from a method in another class?

Tags: java

I am trying to have a string use a method from another class to change a certain character to a different character. However when I run my program nothing happens.

In my main class I have:

```
String example = "example";
Pears.mToX(example);
System.out.println(example);
```

and in my second class called "Pears.java" I have:

```
public static void mToX(String word){
    word.replace("m", "x");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Strings are immutable, meaning they can't be changed, so when you use `replace` it returns the result as a new String, which you're doing nothing with. You'll need to restructure your code like so:

```
String example = "example";
example = Pears.mToX(example);
System.out.println(example);
```

And the method:

```
public static String mToX(String word){
    return word.replace("m", "x");
}
```